# Updating TabBar Badge in Swift Coulld not cast value of type UINavigationController

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, push-notification, uitabbarcontroller

Im trying to set a value to the tab bar item in my tabbar which is created on the storyboard, each time a remote notification is pushed through my app delegate. I keep getting this error:

```
 Could not cast value of type 'UINavigationController' (0x19632c0b0) to 'UITabBarController' (0x19632d230).
```

Code:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    var tabBarController = self.window!.rootViewController as! UITabBarController
        ...
        var tabArray = tabBarController.tabBar.items as NSArray!
        var tabItem = tabArray.objectAtIndex(3) as! UITabBarItem
        tabItem.badgeValue = "34"
        ...
    }
    println("notification")
    //scheduleNotification()
}
```

Comment: Would it be possible to see the layout of your storyboard?

Answer (score 0):

The first line of your posted code

```
var tabBarController = self.window!.rootViewController as! UITabBarController
```

is trying to force a downcast to `UITabBarController`, but self.window!.rootViewController is a `UINavigationController`. In your storyboard, make sure that the tab bar controller is set as the "initial view controller."

Comment: but everything messes up when I set the tab bar controller to initial view controller.

Comment: @AhmedNassar Would it be possible to see a screenshot of your storyboard?